# Javascript chain methods

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a chained methods but I am not being able to do it.

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
};
Person.prototype.walk = function walk(callback) {
   //callback()
};

var person = new Person();
person.walk().walk().walk().walk();
```

Comment: Please provide specific details directly in your question.

Comment: Adding delay using setTimeout is a bad practice. You should look into `Promise`

Comment: I have modified the question..

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, your runtime exception is caused by the functions in your PersonApi not returning the PersonApi object itself, but rather its contained Person object.

In the first call to walk(), this will be fine since walk() will return a person object which has a method 'jump'. However, the 'jump' function of the person object returns undefined, which is why the next call in the chain will produce an error. Change **all** of your API functions to return 'this' instead of 'this.person':

```
    PersonApi.prototype.jump = function(){
      this.person.jump();
      return this;
    };
```

This should produce the expected results.

Comment: True! Thanks, but now, how can I make sure about the order of the calls to be exactly as I call them?

Comment: Unless you're doing asynchronous operations (like setTimeout in your case), they should execute in the same order as you call them. If you want to use asynchronous as you describe, you should probably change your API to use promises. Something like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doktwm1v/)

Answer (score 0):

```
person.walk().jump().run().kneelDown();
```

can be chained if and only if 
    person.walk() 
returns a object/ function which has jump() function within it.
Similarly, person.walk().jump() can be chained only if it returns run() object within it and so forth.

Otherwise the above approach is correct as suggested by @Satchmo Sanders

Answer (score -1):

You have to call the functions individually like this:

```
var person = new PersonApi();
function doAll() {
   //put this function wherever and name it whatever
   person.walk()
   person.jump()
   person.run()
   person.kneelDown();
}
doAll();
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: What do you mean by chained?